# Button click once to update

Tags: javascript, html

I am having an application where a button click on a specific row would update one of the column. It does it all just fine, except that I have to click the update button twice. I believe this could be because of the way I am declaring variables and using them. Below is the code.

HTML

```
  <td><button class="UpdateBtn" onclick="EmpUpdate()">Update</button></td>
```

Js

```
  function EmpUpdate() {
$(".UpdateBtn").on('click', function () {
    var currentRow = $(this).closest("tr");
    var col1 = currentRow.find("td:eq(0)").html();
    var col2 = currentRow.find("td:eq(1)").html();
    var data = [col1, col2];

    $.ajax({
        async: true,
        url: "Home/EmpUpdate?empName=" + col1 + " &empId=" + col2,  
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) { receiveResponse(data); }
    });
    console.log(data);
});
}
```

Comment: onclick is extra in html code. and call EmpUpdate in js after declaring.

Comment: why do you bind a click event inside of a cick event with the same button? That is why you have to click twice....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onclick` event trigges a function and your function is waiting for a click. You have to remove your first line and let the jquery do it or remove `$(".UpdateBtn").on('click'`. Here is a full JQuery answer :

```js
$(".UpdateBtn").on('click', function () {
    var currentRow = $(this).closest("tr");
    var col1 = currentRow.find("td:eq(0)").html();
    var col2 = currentRow.find("td:eq(1)").html();
    var data = [col1, col2];

    $.ajax({
        async: true,
        url: "Home/EmpUpdate?empName=" + col1 + " &empId=" + col2,  
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) { receiveResponse(data); }
    });
    console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td><button class="UpdateBtn">Update</button></td>
```

Comment: Thanks Everyone. I got it.

Comment: Accept a answer to close your question :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to click twice because the first time you click, you invoke `EmpUpdate()` and all it does is set up a `click` event handler for future clicks. So, the second time you click, it works.

Just remove the `onclick` from the HTML and remove the `EmpUpdate()` function and set up the click event when the document is ready.

```
// When the document is ready...
$(function(){
  // Set each element with a class of "UpdateBtn" up with a click event handler
  $(".UpdateBtn").on('click', function () {
    var currentRow = $(this).closest("tr");
    var col1 = currentRow.find("td:eq(0)").html();
    var col2 = currentRow.find("td:eq(1)").html();
    var data = [col1, col2];

    $.ajax({
        async: true,
        url: "Home/EmpUpdate?empName=" + col1 + " &empId=" + col2,  
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) { receiveResponse(data); }
    });
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

do not wrap

> $(".UpdateBtn").on('click', function () {});

inside a function, just put that code outside function and it will register in first place.

```js
$(".UpdateBtn").on('click', function () {
    var currentRow = $(this).closest("tr");
    var col1 = currentRow.find("td:eq(0)").html();
    var col2 = currentRow.find("td:eq(1)").html();
    var data = [col1, col2];

    $.ajax({
        async: true,
        url: "Home/EmpUpdate?empName=" + col1 + " &empId=" + col2,  
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) { receiveResponse(data); }
    });
    console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td><button class="UpdateBtn">Update</button></td>
```

Comment: you also need to remove the inline onclick event.

Comment: Got it! Thank you very much. That helped!